# Document Library Name in xsl

Tags: sharepoint, xslt

I need to grab the document library name in a webpartpages:dataformwebpart

I see the document library names in several places. Which one should I grab?

HeaderTitle="DocLib_23"
DetailLink="/sites/SiteCollection/Project_ABC/SubSite1/DocLib_23/Forms/AllItems.aspx"
Title="DocLib_23"

How do I create a param in xsl to grab the doc lib name from any one of the above?

i.e. Title or HeaderTitle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Some good Links.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd583143(office.11).aspx

2. Add these two line

`<xsl:variable name="DocLibName" select="substring-before(substring-after($PageUrl, '/Forms/'), '/')" />`

`<xsl:param name="PageUrl"/>`

3. set VIEWFLAG=1 (it should be in the properties windows)
4. Find this line and modify if you want Filter the webpart list

`<xsl:variable name="Rows" select="/dsQueryResponse/Rows/Row" />`

Change it to following

`<xsl:variable name="Rows" select="/dsQueryResponse/Rows/Row[(@CustomerNo=$DocLibName)]"/>`

You can use this to display

`<xsl:value-of select="$DocLibName"> <br/>`

`<xsl:value-of select="$PageUrl"/><br/>`